# How can I validate candidates for tracking initialization?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, tracking, matching

I'm working on moving object detection and tracking (Windows 7, OpenCV 2.4.8 in C++ with GPU support).

Right now I have a detection scheme that outputs blobs of interest for every image (example in image below), what I want to do is to deduce which of those are the real objects to validate and offer for tracking.

What would you suggest to compare the detected blobs (or templates, regions etc...) from a few frames in order to see which is consistently detected?

Thanks!

[image: Detected blobs]

Comment: Instead of using the blog segmentation you can train a detector, using cascade of Haar features or HoG...

Comment: probably you should first track them and see what happens. If it's still, or missing after a few frames, you can discard it. Or, if you have a static camera, you can compare your blobs with your background model, and check if it's really a car or a misdetection.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
For this example the objects are cars, but I'm looking for something more general that will detect moving objects in moving camera.

Comment: @G. Für, that would mean training for only cars in a few well defined scenes and scale right?

Comment: @Miki, that's what I was also thinking about, but I'm afraid  it might need too much processing power for my application, I need it to be real time. I'll try it then.

Comment: @Thom object tracking with moving cameras... well a little too broad for an SO question :D However, I'm not that expert on tracking, so I can't help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

so, your cameras are fixed? Using background segmentation on moving cameras can be a trick task, especially if the camera is moving fast.

I would recommend for you to train a simple detector (such as the one 
provided on the OpenCV and see the results). Your images are not that
great, so I think the results could be a bit poor. But keep in mind
to use features that can discriminate well your object from the surroundings (color, shape, etc.).

Once you have a detector you can validade using background segmentation. I
often use the foreground mask to remove the detector false positives that 
I can attest that are in a background area.

Another idea is to use optical flow to remove background blobs that
are not moving (in a consistent manner). 
For that I recommend using a recent method of optical flow (not Lucas-Kanade), such as Prof. Brox:
http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/resources/software.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: No the camera has an unconstrained motion actually, and the scene can be pretty much anything (urban, forest, desert etc...).


I'll take a look at the detector.


I actually have an accepted paper about moving object detection from aerial moving camera using dense optical flow, it works very good, but is nowhere near real time, especially for the embedded application I'm working on right now...


But I'll play around with sparse OF to compare the global motion with the blobs'.


Thanks for your help.